# Blueman connection error (bluetooth issue)

Tags: bluetooth, headphones, bluetooth-speaker, blueman

When trying to connect my bluetooth headphones to my computer using `blueman` I get the following error. 
    Connection Failed: blueman.bluez.errors.DBusFailedError: 
    Resource temporarily unavailable

I am using the Kubuntu flavor of ubuntu. (On a originally `Xubuntu` system)

Comment: Have you search for blue man with sudo apt-cache search blueman or seen if you could run apt-get build-dep blueman, if you were to run service blueman status, what is the error message

Answer (score 35):

I had to unpair/pair my device again. [Restarting bluetooth service](https://askubuntu.com/a/1051977) didn't help.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/877139)

Comment: @guntbert: The first sentence looks like an answer to me.

Comment: @DavidFoerster no, it is a comment on https://askubuntu.com/a/1051977/134729 .

Comment: @guntbert: The second sentence certainly appear to be a comment to that. The first sentence is a valid, self-contained answer. (I cannot confirm its veracity but that doesn’t matter to its classification as an answer here.)

Comment: Actually this did help and now I'm connected to my bluetooth device.

Comment: I have a bose bluetooth headset. I had to remove the configurations both on the computer and on the headset. You can remove the config for the headset through the app on your phone.

Comment: This answer solved my problem as well.

Answer (score 7):

run this to reset its configuration. turn off and on bluetooth and connect bluetooth headphone again. i had same issue on ubuntu 16.10 and it solve it! in this case you don't need blueman. run this and in Sound setting select your headphone

```
rm -r ~/.config/pulse; pulseaudio -k
```

Comment: It still didnt work

Comment: I get "Connection Failed: blueman.bluez.errors.DBusFailedError: Host is down" now

Comment: restart system. don't use blueman and etc. just restart system, then turn on bluetooth and connect. then go to sound setting and select headphone. hope it helps

Comment: I've tried restarting. It didnt work. I'll look for blueman alternatives though

Comment: This works for me, thank. 
Is there a more permanent fix for this ?

Answer (score 5):

I often have this issue:

> blueman.bluez.errors.DBusFailedError: Resource temporarily unavailable

with blueman on Ubuntu Mate 18.04 when waking the machine up from suspension.

Simply restarting the bluetooth service with:

```
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

and rescanning usually resolves the issue quite easily.

Comment: worked for ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 5):

I used the following command and it solved my problem:

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

Then try to reconnect your bluetooth headset.

Comment: Thank you! Arch users install the following aur: "pulseaudio-modules-bt" and restart bluetooth "sudo systemctl restart bluetooth". 
No need to reconnect anything. Just works as it should. Awesome!

Comment: My god... I almost gave up on a 250€ headset... this worked on Ubuntu 20.04 and had tried dozens of things...

Answer (score 2):

Try restarting Pulse Audio, as also mentioned above. These commands worked for me.

```
pulseaudio --kill
pulseaudio -vvv --start
```

Answer (score 1):

I received this error as the headset was already connected to another device (my phone). Check that the device you are wanting to connect to your Ubuntu instance is not already connected to another device, such as a mobile telephone, and then try to connect again.

Answer (score 1):

One very easy thing you have to try before anything else, is check that there isn't any other device that is already connected to the device via bluetooth. For me it was my phone, which was connecting to a bluetooth speaker automatically. Once I disconnected it and restarted bluetooth adapter on my machine it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Plugalbe USB Bluetooth adaptor and ran into a similar problem.  As their website site explains; "issue stems from a lack of support for these profiles on the Broadcom BCM20702 chipset found inside our device". The site provided a BCM20702 firmware update file with installation instructions which worked for me.  Here's a link to that site. I hope this helps. https://plugable.com/2014/06/23/plugable-usb-bluetooth-adapter-solving-hfphsp-profile-issues-on-linux/