# bluetooth headset: connect/disconnect problems

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, sony

How to change from cellphone to desktop without having to pair everything every time?

Every time I disconnect the device, toggling to off the connection toggle, if I try to toggle it back to on again there's no sound coming out.

I can get a very dirty sound if I go to sound settings and set the mode to HSP/HFP, but then if I try to come back to High Fidelity (Sink), the app jumps to the speakers output. So I'm trapped in either no sound or very dirty sound.

The only way out is delete the previous pairing and pairing it up again.

If I don't toggle of connection, I cannot pair it with my android.

Tried it with blueman, but didn't seem of much help.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I have the same problem with the dirty sound quality, but I haven't fixed it; my workaround is to explicitly set to HSP/HFP, then disconnect, reconnect and *then* switch to High Fidelity, which usually works (but is kind of a hassle). I'm using blueman.

Answer (score 0):

Try the answer from here [Blueman connection error (bluetooth issue)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/875881/blueman-connection-error-bluetooth-issue#875891)

> rm -r ~/.config/pulse; pulseaudio -k