# JBL Bluetooth Speaker not connecting in bluetooth devices in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 in Dell laptop

Tags: 16.04, drivers, bluetooth, ubuntu-gnome, bluetooth-speaker

I am trying to connect my JBL bluetooth speaker via Bluetooth with my Dell Laptop (Ubuntu Gnome 16.04).

I am able to find JBL speakers in the list of available bluetooth devices after turning on bluetooth in my laptop. However I am unable to connect it to my laptop.

[See Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2kqK.png) However the speaker works fine in my laptop Windows and also from my android phone. So I guess this is a bluetooth driver problem in Ubuntu.

The following is the output of `lspci` command:

```
 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
 00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
 00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
 00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
 00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
 0:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
 00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
 00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
 00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
 00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
 00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
 00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
 00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
 06:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
 07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
 08:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
```

If someone knows the procedure to fix this issue, please do answer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think listing USB devices is relevant for the question? Your Bluetooth chipset isn't USB, most likely PCI and the same device as the WiFi. How exactly have you been trying to pair the speakers? It's not clear you know what you're, all the opposite actually.

Comment: I am trying to pair with Bluetooth.

Comment: You don't say... How exactly are you doing that? Please [edit] your question, remove the "noise" (lsusb list) and describe what are you doing (and try `lspci` instead and post the line referring to your actual BT device only, everything else is superfluous).

Comment: I have edited the question as per your suggestions. My speaker is a bluetooth speaker and I am trying to connect it to my laptop by using bluetooth. But I am not even able to see the device in the list of available bluetooth devices after turning on bluetooth

Comment: Simply turning on Bluetooth isn't enough, hence my comment about you probably not knowing what you're doing... (In 16.04 and up to 17.04, 17.10 is slightly different) You need to go to Bluetooth settings and press the + sign to search for new devices. When listed select it to pair. This is done once. Next step is opening sound settings and select the speakers, it isn't automatic unlike other OSes.

Comment: I am not able to add the new device in bluetooth. I can only add a new bluetooth device if the laptop is able to discover it right. 

This is the screenshot of my bluetooth settings. You can see that my laptop is unable to find "JBL GO".

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOOF4.png
 There is no + sign to add a new device. The only procedure to add a new device is to click on it when it appears in this list of available devices.

Comment: That is NOT Ubuntu 16.04. What OS are you running exactly?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu Gnome 16.04. I have edited the description.

Comment: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-connect-via-bluetooth-in-gnome/ Of course, make sure the speakers are in pairing mode, i.e., "discoverable". Refer to the user's manual. Speakers typically have an "always on" pairing mode but a quick google search revealed JBLs are tricky, some models need to be un-paired before being paired to a new device (even if it's the same PC, running a different OS makes it a "new device", same caveats apply). In an nutshell, if it sees other BT devices but not the speakers in the correct mode, there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: I have restarted my speaker several times and for some reason I now begin to see it in the list of available devices in my laptop. But I am not able to connect the speaker though. The connection button in the image ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2kqK.png ) just momentarily goes to ON and then goes back OFF.

I have also tried removing the device and connecting again. Didnt work

Comment: Nothing else to add. Google is your friend.

Comment: > The connection button in the image ( i.stack.imgur.com/b2kqK.png ) just momentarily goes to ON and then goes back OFF. I have also tried removing the device and connecting again. Didnt work I had the exact same problem. This worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/1062044