# Ubuntu 20.04.3 Intermittent bluetooth connections

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, blueman

I'm facing intermittent bluetooth connection issues where I can connect a device on startup and after a while (30mins) the connection will be degraded (skipping/jittery). If I then disconnect the device and attempt to reconnect it from `blueman-manager` I get the following two cases:

1. A successful connection, after which the device is not listed as an ouptut in `pavucontrol`
2. Connection error: `Connection Failed:  Resource temporarily unavailable`

### Solutions attempted

1. Unpairing/repairing the device
2. Resetting the pulseaudio config (https://askubuntu.com/a/875891/1569612)
3. Restarting pavucontrol (`pulseaudio -k`) or restarting bluetooth (`systemctl restart bluetooth.service`)
4. Attempting to reload pulseaudio-discovery module (https://askubuntu.com/a/1062044/1569612)
   Above yeilds the following error

```
taylorswift2018@box:~$ pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
Failure: Module initialization failed
```

5. Load pulseaudio after x11 (https://askubuntu.com/a/689297/1569612)

The output of `systemctl status bluetooth.service`

```
taylorswift2018@box:~$ systemctl status bluetooth.service 
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-02-10 10:31:33 NZDT; 1h 49min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 821 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18965)
     Memory: 1.9M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─821 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Feb 10 10:31:33 box bluetoothd[821]: Starting SDP server
Feb 10 10:31:33 box bluetoothd[821]: Bluetooth management interface 1.20 initialized
Feb 10 10:31:34 box bluetoothd[821]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.41 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Feb 10 10:31:34 box bluetoothd[821]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.41 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Feb 10 10:31:49 box bluetoothd[821]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_16_94_29_CD_9E/sep1/fd0: fd(46) ready
Feb 10 12:09:15 box bluetoothd[821]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Feb 10 12:10:35 box bluetoothd[821]: Disconnecting failed: already disconnected
Feb 10 12:10:37 box bluetoothd[821]: Unable to get Headset Voice gateway SDP record: Operation already in progress
Feb 10 12:10:37 box bluetoothd[821]: connect error: Operation already in progress (114)
Feb 10 12:10:39 box bluetoothd[821]: connect error: Operation already in progress (114)
```

- `journalctl` is not showing any errors

#### Hardware

- CPU: Intel i7 11700
- Motherboard: Gigabyte B560M DS3H AC

```
taylorswift2018@box:~$ inxi -Fxxxz
System:
  Kernel: 5.13.0-28-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.36.9 wm: gnome-shell dm: GDM3 3.36.3 
  Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Desktop Mobo: Gigabyte model: B560M DS3H AC v: x.x serial: <filter> 
  UEFI: American Megatrends LLC. v: F6 date: 08/23/2021 
CPU:
  Topology: 8-Core model: 11th Gen Intel Core i7-11700 bits: 64 type: MT MCP 
  arch: N/A L2 cache: 16.0 MiB 
  flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx 
  bogomips: 79872 
  Speed: 800 MHz min/max: 800/4800 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 800 2: 800 
  3: 800 4: 800 5: 813 6: 807 7: 1045 8: 825 9: 2193 10: 4613 11: 4651 
  12: 1586 13: 4693 14: 1214 15: 4499 16: 4541 
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] 
  vendor: ASRock driver: amdgpu v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.0 chip ID: 1002:67df 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: amdgpu compositor: gnome-shell 
  resolution: 2560x1440~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Radeon RX 570 Series (POLARIS10 DRM 3.41.0 
  5.13.0-28-generic LLVM 12.0.0) 
  v: 4.6 Mesa 21.2.6 direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel vendor: Gigabyte driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
  bus ID: 00:1f.3 chip ID: 8086:43c8 
  Device-2: AMD Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590] 
  vendor: ASRock driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.1 
  chip ID: 1002:aaf0 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.13.0-28-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet 
  vendor: Gigabyte driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 4000 bus ID: 03:00.0 
  chip ID: 10ec:8168 
  IF: enp3s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter 
  vendor: AzureWave driver: rtl8821ce v: v5.5.2.1_35598.20191029 port: 3000 
  bus ID: 04:00.0 chip ID: 10ec:c821 
  IF: wlp4s0 state: up mac: <filter> 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 2.27 TiB used: 25.01 GiB (1.1%) 
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Western Digital model: WD20EFRX-68EUZN0 
  size: 1.82 TiB speed: 6.0 Gb/s rotation: 5400 rpm serial: <filter> 
  rev: 0A82 scheme: GPT 
  ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Samsung model: SSD 860 EVO 500GB size: 465.76 GiB 
  speed: 6.0 Gb/s serial: <filter> rev: 4B6Q scheme: GPT 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 456.96 GiB used: 25.00 GiB (5.5%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdb2 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 42.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: amdgpu temp: 27 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A gpu: amdgpu fan: 1438 
Info:
  Processes: 372 Uptime: 1h 21m Memory: 15.50 GiB used: 2.05 GiB (13.2%) 
  Init: systemd v: 245 runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.3.0 alt: 9 Shell: bash 
  v: 5.0.17 running in: server inxi: 3.0.38
```

Answer (score 1):

After trying out a the open source driver from the gnome driver panel
[driver-panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNwZY.png) and still seeing problems I decided to build and update the driver myself as I believe the `apt` version of this package is outdated. Installing this driver using the [following](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce) remote and instructions and restarting gave back consistent bluetooth behavior

Edit: No it didn't and i've given up and decided not to use wireless as a workaround because i've burnt enough time on this garbage.

Comment: Could you please add the steps you followed to your answer, in case the link dies in future?

Comment: @Zanna No. Also this ended up being a red herring.  I've had to revert to using everything as wired. I'll see if a bluetooth dongle over using my motherboards onboard bluetooth

Comment: Bluetooth dongle works perfectly.