# Bluetooth can't connect to devices in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: bluetooth, 22.04, toshiba-satellite

I recently updated to 22.04 and Bluetooth is not working. It appears as enabled but when I try to connect to any device it does not work. It looks as if it didn't event try it.
Here I include some possibly useful info:

```
$ lsusb

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0138 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5138 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0cf3:3005 Qualcomm Atheros Communications AR3011 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5801 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB Camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ sudo dmesg | grep -i blue

[    3.807491] toshiba_bluetooth: Toshiba ACPI Bluetooth device driver
[    3.944674] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.947355] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    3.947357] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.947362] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.947368] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.947376] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    6.132002] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.132007] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.132012] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   37.465184] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   37.465197] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   37.465207] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it using [this method](https://askubuntu.com/a/1062044/1625388). Credit to ReXa.

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```